# Place image arbitrarily over another image using css

Tags: html, css, image

There are several similar questions posted, but none that I found addresses my situation.

I would like to list items for sale, each in their own div.  When an item sells, I'd like to place a transparent "sold" banner over any such item without fully obscuring the image. I will need to delegate someone else to add the "sold" banner in the code without the need for me to do this.  So the simpler the method, the better.

Most, if not all, solutions on this site recommend creating the overlapping banner image in an absolutely positioned div.  That secondary div contains an img src.  This is looking like a lot more code to confuse the helper.

I gather it would be semantic and a lot easier if the transparent SOLD banner were a background.  If I'm not mistaken, then all that would be needed is a simple class to add to any existing div. For example:

```
    <div><img src="folder/item3.png"></div>
```

... becomes

```
    <div><img src="folder/item3.png" class="sold"></div>
```

... thus doing away with a second div to contain the SOLD graphic.  I tried this, and it appeared to work, but the banner remained stubbornly behind the item and no amount of Z-indexing and absolute positioning would get it out front where it belongs.  (Actually I can't absolutely position this anyway since it interferes with the overall layout.)

I hope that someone can suggest a way to do this that solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant use a background of the div containing the image because the background would always be under it. Unless you want to set the product image itself to a background and then just put the sold graphic into it as an image.

What I would do is, firstly you need your div containing your image to be position:relative. Then put another div inside it for the sold icon which is positioned absolute. z-index the sold icon above it.

e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/z2V2B/1/

html

```
<div class="imgholder"><div class="soldicon"></div><img src="http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/hypebeast-wordpress/image/2009/07/huf-converse-product-red-skidgrip-1.jpg" width="250"></div>

<div class="imgholder sold"><div class="soldicon"></div><img src="http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/hypebeast-wordpress/image/2009/07/huf-converse-product-red-skidgrip-1.jpg" width="250"></div>
```

css

```
.imgholder {position:relative; z-index:1;}

.soldicon {position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    top:0; 
    left:0;
width:177px; 
    height:138px;
    background:url(http://www.flq.co.nz/images/icon-sold.gif) no-repeat top left;
}

.sold .soldicon {display:block!important;}

.soldicon {display:none;}
```

-- ADDITIONAL 30/05/14--

If the SOLD label is overlapping the image -- which was originally linked to another page

...dit the code so that the sold div also has a link inside it to the same place as the image. Then add the following css:

```
.soldicon a {text-indent:-9000px; display:block; width:100%; height:100%;}
```

what this will do is create an invisible link (because the text will be indented off the page that is the full width and height of the sold icon div - it will seemlessly be as if the whole image is clickable again and not obscured by the sold icon

Comment: mistake in my fiddle, now updated. We have a sold class now as well. It only shows when the holder div is class=sold

Comment: Looks good, but this renders the same result I originally had.  In other words, the SOLD icon remains behind the image.  You can see the work I'm trying at http://direalty.ca/test.php, the last featured image.

Comment: For me, i got it to work on your site. By specifying width and height for the soldicon class (the same as your sold image) e.g:
width:164px;
height:123px;

Comment: Yes, indeed.  I had specified those dimensions during numerous tries and removed them in an attempt to make it work.  It appears that now the pieces are all fitting, albeit some styling will be needed to make it resize at a lower screen width.  Thanks a million.

Comment: And now I've tidied it up even more.  I completely nixed the "sold" class from the CSS and the code.  Additionally, I've removed the .soldicon class from the other featured images, and it still works.  Not sure why, but it does.

Comment: ... by simply adding <div class="soldicon"></div> to the appropriate div.  And that's what I wanted in the first place since it's succinct enough for a novice to handle.  I'll check back here, and I hope you'll let me know if this minimal arrangement is not a good idea. :)

Comment: All of this came to a screaming halt when I discovered that with the SOLD label overlapping the image -- which was originally linked to another page -- that link was effectively lost because it is now obscured in the stacking order.  I don't know if there's a remedy for this, but I invite your wisdom nonetheless.

Comment: Ah, I have encountered this before. What you need to do is edit the code so that the sold div also has a link inside it to the same place as the image. Then add the following css:
.soldicon a {text-indent:-9000px; display:block; width:100%; height:100%;} what this will do is create an invisible link (because the text will be indented off the page that is the full width and height of the sold icon div - it will seemlessly be as if the whole image is clickable again and not obscured by the sold icon

Comment: Worked like a charm.  You're a star!

Comment: no worries - i have edited my answer above. maybe worth an up vote now?